# Thinking Sphinx filtering on a string field in a has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, filtering, thinking-sphinx

Can't tell what's wrong here. I'm trying to filter on the `state` property of my `address` association.

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, :as => :addressable, :dependent => :destroy

  define_index do
    indexes :name, :sortable => true

    has mec_revenue
    has 'CRC32(status)', :as => :status, :type => :integer
    has 'CRC32(address.state)', :as => :state, :type => :integer
    set_property :delta => true
  end

end
```

But when I run `rake ts:index`, I get the error below.

```
indexing index 'organization_delta'...
ERROR: index 'organization_delta': sql_range_query: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "address"
LINE 1: ...S "mec_revenue", CRC32(status) AS "status", CRC32(address.st...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how to fix the FROM-clause problem, but if I use the table name instead of the property name, I can fix this with a `group_by` clause.

```
has 'CRC32(addresses.state)', :as => :state, :type => :integer
group_by "addresses.state"
```